# WP customizer, append to dom

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, append, freeze

I try to make panels/controls/settings etc.
Here is php

```js
add_action( 'customize_register', 'gx_customizer_init' );
function gx_customizer_init( WP_Customize_Manager $wp_customize ){    
    //some another code

    foreach($themes as $theme) {
        foreach($switches as $name => $label) {
            //added more than 90 control
            $wp_customize->add_setting( $name.$theme.'-color-dark', [
                'default'   => '#000000',
                'transport' => $transport
            ] );
            $wp_customize->add_control( $name.$theme.'-color-dark', [
                'section'  => $section,
                'type'     => 'color',
                'label'    => $label
            ] );
        }
    }
}
```

In js I try to change some tags/controls (created by wp customizer)

```js
wp.customize.bind('pane-contents-reflowed', function () { 
   let darkLi = document.querySelectorAll("li[id*='-color-dark']");//get colors for light section
   let lightLi = document.querySelectorAll("li[id*='-color-light']");//get colors for light section
   $('#customize-control-darkColors ul').append(darkLi); //add colors in light section
   $('#customize-control-lightColors ul').append(lightLi); //add colors in light section
}
```

The page getting freeze . When I remove append part (moving elements), it works without freezing, freezing still exist even if I append one `li`  or append with vanilla js.
What can cause freezing ?

Comment: You're appending NodeLists instead of an array of elements. See [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).

Comment: So , does that cause freezing? 
Same result with
`$('#customize-control-darkColors ul').append($("li[id*='-color-dark']"))`

Comment: And same with `$('#customize-control-darkColors ul').append(Array.prototype.slice.call(darkLi))`